# Create different tables dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a code where in I'll need to create Tables dynamically. And here one of the experts in SO helped me on creating them, but here I'm looking to create the tables seperately.

Currently it is like

```
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I want it as

```
  <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and here is the working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9r6a1uby/2/

please let me know on how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Looks ok to me. What is the issue ?

Comment: is just indent ?

Comment: In my actual output all the content is in a single table, but here i want the data in 4 different tables

Comment: Basically what you want to do is to create multiple tables for each item in the list. For this you should make the #excelDataTable a <div></div> and append <table></table> with the necessary data to it like you are doing instead of appending tr, th, td to the <table></table>

Comment: @Ashniu123 exactly, you got me... This is what I'm unable understand on how to do

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body  onLoad="buildHtmlTable()">
    <div id="excelDataTable">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

 var myList = [
  [{
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "0.575",
    "ruleNo": "1",
    "ingredients": "sulphates",
    "id": "2"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "10.25",
    "ruleNo": "1",
    "ingredients": "alcohol",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "98.5",
    "ruleNo": "1",
    "ingredients": "total sulfur dioxide",
    "id": "3"
  }],
  [{
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "1.98",
    "ruleNo": "3",
    "ingredients": "sulphates",
    "id": "8"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "81.5",
    "ruleNo": "3",
    "ingredients": "total sulfur dioxide",
    "id": "9"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "10.25",
    "ruleNo": "3",
    "ingredients": "alcohol",
    "id": "7"
  }],
  [{
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "98.5",
    "ruleNo": "2",
    "ingredients": "total sulfur dioxide",
    "id": "6"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "0.575",
    "ingredients": "sulphates",
    "id": "5"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "10.25",
    "ruleNo": "2",
    "ingredients": "alcohol",
    "id": "4"
  }],
  [{
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "1.98",
    "ruleNo": "4",
    "ingredients": "sulphates",
    "id": "11"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "155",
    "ruleNo": "4",
    "ingredients": "total sulfur dioxide",
    "id": "12"
  }, {
    "product": "Red Wine",
    "unit": " ",
    "max": "10.25",
    "min": "8.5",
    "target_state": "5",
    "min_operator": "<=",
    "max_operator": " ",
    "target_parameter": "Quality",
    "ruleNo": "4",
    "ingredients": "alcohol",
    "id": "10"
  }]
];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
function buildHtmlTable() {
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList[0], i);

    for (var j = 0; j < myList[i].length; j++) {
      var row$ = $('<tr/>');
      console.log(myList[i][j])
      for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {

        var cellValue =  myList[i][j][columns[colIndex]];

        if (cellValue == null) {
            cellValue = "";
        }

        row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
      }
      $("#table-id-"+i).append(row$);
    }
  }

  // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
  // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
  // all records
  function addAllColumnHeaders(list, i) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = '<table id="table-id-'+i+'"><thead><tr>';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var rowHash = list[i];
      for (var key in rowHash) {
        if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
          columnSet.push(key);
          headerTr$ += '<th>' + key + '</th>';
        }
      }
    }

    headerTr$ += '</tr></thead></table>';
    console.log(headerTr$);
    $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);
    return columnSet;
  }
}


    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Generate table id dynamically and then append data for that table. May it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

Replace your functions with the code below, this should fix your problem

**HTML**

```
<body onLoad="buildHtmlTable()">
   <div id="tables-div"></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function buildHtmlTable() {
   for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
       var $table = $('<table id="excelDataTable-'+(i+1)+'"  border="1"></table>');
       $('#tables-div').append($table);
       var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList[0], (i+1));

       for (var j = 0; j < myList[i].length; j++) {
           var row$ = $('<tr/>');
           console.log(myList[i][j])
           for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {

               var cellValue =  myList[i][j][columns[colIndex]];

               if (cellValue == null) {
                   cellValue = "";
               }

               row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
               $("#excelDataTable-"+(i+1)).append(row$)
           }

       }
      $('#tables-div').append('<br />');
}


function addAllColumnHeaders(myList, table_id) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $("#excelDataTable"+table_id).append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
  }
}
```